# Learning PDO queries

Tags: mysql, pdo

FIXED!
The problem was I didn't know you had to initialize a connection to PDO separate from a normal connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

I'm trying to learn PDO for security purposes + just good practices. Is this correct on how I would translate an insert query into PDO? It doesn't seem to be working. $dbh has to be my connection to the server correct?

```
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (social_id, name, email, social_network, profile_pic) VALUES (:social_id, :name, :email, :social_network, :profile_pic)");
                        $stmt->bindParam(':social_id', $social_id);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':social_network', $social_network);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':profile_pic', $profile_pic);

                        // insert one row
                        $stmt->execute(); 

                        $user_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

From this:

```
                          mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (social_id, name, email, social_network, profile_pic)
                                            VALUES ('$social_id', '$name','$email', '$social_network','$profile_pic')");                

                            $user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't need to create extra variables - just use the ones you already have in the `bindParam` calls.

Comment: The problem was I didn't know you had to initialize a connection to PDO separate from a normal connection: 

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

Comment: Please post your answer *as an answer*.  If not, then this will have to be closed as not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't know you had to initialize a connection to PDO separate from a normal connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```